# Is it possible to get more details about the device characteristics in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to know more details about the device on which my app is running in order to keep some statistics. I discover how to get the device manufacturer, using the DeviceExtendedProperties class.

```
    DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("DeviceManufacturer", out param)
```

Is it possible to find out as well the model (example "Lumnia 1020") or the screen size (in inch)? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This guy wrote a small utility class to find the device manufacturer and model, as well as some other useful system properties:

[SystemInfoHelper on Github](https://gist.github.com/HamGuy/8294463)